# Cannot find module '../assets/json/example.json'

Tags: json, angular, typescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQVI0.png)**strong text**

Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension

Comment: Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension

Answer (score 5):

open File `tsconfig.json` and change resolveJsonModule : to true.

```
{
    resolveJsonModule:true,
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to solve it this way. Its work for me.
Create file called `json-typings.d.ts` in `src/app` folder.
and typing file as follows:

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

Then you can import Json files just like TypeScript 2.9+.

```
import * as info from "info.json";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add in your tslint.json file

```
{
   "linterOptions": {
       "exclude": [
          "*.json",
          "**/*.json"
       ]  
   }
}
```

**/*.json to be recursive

Comment: bro how to find tslint.json file??

Comment: just hit ctrl + p if windows or if MAC cmd + p and type "tslint.json" if you are using vscode or else just find tslint.json file. this file is created by default when an angular project is created with cli

Answer (score 0):

Copy this in your   **tsconfig.json** file , inside `compilerOptions`:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
```